# Unsure how to set circle.fillColor in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

This is the code I wrote to try and set the `circle.fillColor` attribute.  The `if` statement doesn't work.  Could anyone provide suggestions?

```
function cicle:touch( event )
    --if (event.phase == "began") and (circle.fillColor == red) then 
     score = score + 1
     playerScore.text = "Score: " .. score
    --end
  end
```

Comment: but the "if" doesnt work

Comment: add more code and be specific in what you say ?

Comment: You need to add more code and explain what errors you have when running your app. Corona shapes (circle in your case) don't have a fillColor attribute or function.

Comment: You probably mean string `"red"` not `red`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have typo. The function says cicle:touch but I think you want circle:touch.

Here you are checking if circle.fillColor is a variable (red). If you do  it that way you need to create variable red and add string "red" to it. But here is a far simpler way:

```
local score
local circle = display.newCircle(display.contentCenterX,     display.contentCenterY, 20)

circle.fillColor = "red"

function circleTouch( event )
     if (event.phase == "began") and (circle.fillColor == "red") then        
                  score = score + 1
                  playerScore.text = "Score: " .. score .. ""
          end
  end
  circle:addEventListener("touch", circleTouch)
```